# Remove mediaelement properly from grid

Tags: wpf, grid, element, media

I am new to WPF. In my application I am displaying a list of video titles in one column of grid (**gridTitle**), and in another column I add one more grid (**gridVideo**) which contains a media element (within usercontrol) and play the video which is selected on **gridTitle**. As user selects the different title from **gridTitle**, I remove media element(usercontrol) as follows

```
if(gridVideo.Children.Count > 0)
{
    MediaControl temp = null;
    foreach (UIElement element in gridVideo.Children)
    {
        if (element.GetType() == typeof(MediaControl))
            temp = (MediaControl)element;    
    }

    if(temp!=null)
        gridVideo.Children.Remove(temp);

    // gridMedia.Children.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

above method removes the user control which contains media element. Here I want to ask whether there are any need to stop/close current video which is playing or it will be automatically handled by WPF. My main concerns is that whether media element does not download data in buffer in background?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely necessary to replace that control with the MediaElement? You could just reset its MediaElement's `Source` property according to the selected title. This can be done using data binding: the displayed titles could be instances of a class that contains Title (for displaying in a list) and Uri (to set the `MediaElement.Source` property). Then `MediaElement.Source` is bound to the `SelectedItem.Uri` of items container.

Comment: there are a list of information which is attached to video. So i create a user control which contains media element and other control. So media element display the video and other control show the related information like title, description, rating, resolution etc. and there are 100 + video and each of contains this information. so when user click on any item then i remove previous user control and add new user control one in grid

Comment: All the information may be data bound, there still is no need to replace the user control itself. Event if it had to be bound to different classes. Just place mediaelement in that user control alongside with other elements you need to display data. Pass selected instance into user control's DataContext and bound everything there